# Tax calculation not correct

Tags: mysql

I have an error in this query, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? This query works until I try and discount something at 100%. At 100%, I'm getting a $10.99 tax on an $11.25 item. The tax should show 0.00.

```
      (tax_state + tax_fed)/100*(SUM( t3.price * t1.quantity)*SUM( t3.price * t1.quantity)-(SUM(t1.discount) + t3.discount)/100)
```

EDIT:

This works now and gives me the correct tax but is a negative number. It shouldn't be negative.

```
(SUM(price*quantity)*(SUM(discount)+t3.discount)/100-SUM(price*quantity))*(tax_state+tax_fed)/100 AS tax
```

Comment: What is the schema? Without that information it's pretty hard to give a full answer to your question.

Comment: Can you explain to me why the schema is needed?

Comment: Your number of parentheses is not even correct. Can you post some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calculating the discount wrong. your math boils down to:

```
taxes * ( (cost * cost) - discount)
```

which means you're squaring the cost, subtracting a small discount value, and multiple by taxes. Most likely you'd want something more like

```
taxes * (cost - (cost * discount))
```

or, doing some algebraic extraction

```
taxes * cost * (1 - discount)
```

instead, which'd be

```
(tax_state + tax_fed)/100 * SUM(t3.price * t1.quantity) * (1 - (SUM(t1.discount) + t3.discount) / 100)
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the help. I've posted a revised version of my code which seems to give me back the correct total tax but as a negative number. I'll compare what you've given me to what I have. Thanks for helping...

Comment: Well, now you're doing "(discounted value - full value) * taxes" (e.g. ($90 - $100) * 5%). Swap the order of the discount/full values and it should work out ok.